# How to check for array contents in Google Firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document `boxes/box-xyz` which contains an array `owners`. This array contains `uid`s of users who own the document and all documents in sub-collections. Example: `{owners: ["uid123", "uid456"]}`.

Now I want to write a rule which checks if the current user's `uid` is in this array. I tried with the array function `includes`, but it is not usable in the rules file.

So how do I check if the current user is one of the owners of a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` operator of the [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) type object you get from that field.

```
allow someop: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.owners;
```